# an example of a representation

Tags: representation-theory

This is an example given in the representation theory book:

> Let $\rho : S_3 → GL_2(\mathbb C)\qquad$ be specified on the generators $(1 2)$ and $(1 2 3)$
>   by $\rho _{(1 2)} =$ $\begin{bmatrix}
>     -1 & -1 \\
>     0 & 1 \\ 
>     \end{bmatrix}$,
>   $\rho_{(1 2 3)} =\begin{bmatrix}
>     -1 & -1 \\
>     1 & 0 \\ 
>     \end{bmatrix}$
>   Claim: $\rho _{(1 2)}$ and $\rho _{(1 23)}$ do not have a common eigenvector.
>   Indeed, direct computation reveals $\rho _{(1 2)}$ has eigenvalues $1$ and $−1$ with
>   $V_{−1} = \mathbb C e_1$ and $V_1 =\mathbb C \begin{bmatrix}
>     -1 \\
>     2  \\ 
>     \end{bmatrix}$

First of all, how do they compute $V_{−1}$ and $V_{1}$? Also, what do $V_{−1}$ and $V_{1}$ specify?

> Clearly $e_1$ is not an eigenvector of $\rho _{(1 2 3)}$ as
>   $\rho _{(1 2 3)}\begin{bmatrix}
>     1 \\
>     0  \\ 
>     \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
>     -1 \\
>     1  \\ 
>     \end{bmatrix}$
>    .
>   Also,
>   $\rho _{(1 2 3)}\begin{bmatrix}
>     -1 \\
>     2  \\ 
>     \end{bmatrix}
>  = \begin{bmatrix}
>     -1 \\
>     -1  \\ 
>     \end{bmatrix}$
>    ,
>   so (−1, 2) is not an eigenvector of $\rho _{(1 2 3)}$. Thus $\rho _{(1 2 )}$ and $\rho _{(1 2 3)}$ have no common eigenvector, which implies that $\rho$ is irreducible.

Secondly what is the reasoning made above while finding eigenvectors?
Also when I try to compute eigenvalues for $\rho _{(1 2 3)}$ , I get $\lambda^2+\lambda +1=0$ which does not have real roots

Comment: Do you know how to compute eigenvectors? Because, they just computed them. Also, a matrix can have real valued eigenvectors even though the eigenvalues are complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of $A=\begin{pmatrix}-1&-1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ is $\det\begin{pmatrix}-1-X&-1\\0&1-X\end{pmatrix}=-(1+X)(1-X)=X^2-1$. Hence the eigenvalues are $\pm 1$. The space $V_1$ is $V_1=N(A-1\cdot Id)$ by definition, that is the solutions to the system $(A-Id)X=0$. Easy calculation shows that $V_1=\text{Span}[(-1,2)]$. Similarly, $V_{-1}=\text{Span}[(1,0)]$.

Let $B=\begin{pmatrix}
-1&1\\1&0
\end{pmatrix}$. Simple calculations show that neither $(-1,2)$ or $(1,0)$ are eigenvectors of $B$. Thus $A$ and $B$ share no eigenvectors. No need to compute the eigenvectors of $B$ explicitly!

Comment: Oh,thanks! I didn't think that by " the notation $\mathbb C$ " they were actually intending to mean spanning.

Comment: It's common notation, it is only used for one-dimensional spaces :)